# how to debug mapGetter property in Vue.js component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, console.log, vscode-debugger

I am new to Vue.js. I have recently learned Vuex and trying to implement in my project. 
I am calling calling an action dispatch from my `dashboard` component. And calling ...mapGetter in `message` component computed section. And I want to debug the data that I am getting.

I already searched my problem. But couldn't find it. What I learned I can't use console.log() in computed. I have to use debugger. But when I am using debugger it's saying debugger is a reserved word.

in my store:

```
  state: {
    conversationThreads: [],
    conversation: [],
    users: [],
  },
  getters: {
    conversation: state => {
      return state.conversation;
    }

  },
  mutations: {
    [MUTATION_TYPES.SET_CONVERSATION](state, conversationThread){
      state.conversation= conversationThread;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getConversationByID: ({ commit }, conversationInfo) => {
      console.log("conversationData: ", conversationInfo)
      axios.get("https://some_API" + conversationInfo.id)
        .then(response => {
          let conversationThread = response.data.messages.data.map(res => ({
            name: res.from.name,
            msg: res.message
          }));
          commit(MUTATION_TYPES.SET_CONVERSATION, conversationThread);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
```

in my dashboard component:

```
        methods: {
            selectedDiv: function(conversationInfo, event){
              this.$store.dispatch('getConversationByID', conversationInfo)

            }

        }
```

in my message component:

```
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        "conversation"
      ]),
      debugger
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get similar functionality without using `mapGetter`, below is example.

```
computed: {
    yourProperty(){
        const profile = this.$store.getters.profile;
        console.log('profile: ', profile); //Debug
        return profile;
    }
},
```

Another option is to put a watch on computed property.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["profile"]),
},

watch: {
    profile: {
        handler(profile) {
            console.log('profile: ', profile); //Debug
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

Here deep true option is used to watch on key updates of `profile` object. If deep true is not provided then watch will get called only when `profile` getter is reassigned with new object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is really helpful. But the main purpose of my question was to know the reason, why it's giving an error of 'debugger is a reserved word.' 
Why we can't use console.log or debugger in computed.

Comment: What do you mean by using console.log in computed, computed :{} object contains different properties which are nothing but a methods which returns some data after some computation, It literally doesn't make any sense to put console.log as another property.